# android - overdraw layout allows touch through LinearLayout

Tags: android, controls, touch, overlay, android-linearlayout

in the following UI I have this below drabable overlaying the entire screen. The LinearLayout is transparent and allows controls below it to be clickable or touchable. Basically I can scroll a list below this LinearLayout as well as click controls. How do I disable that?

See attached example.[image]

Thank you

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/rlExtNavbar" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="Overdraw">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandedNavbarLayout" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparentLayout" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/expandedNavbarLayout"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@color/fulltransparent">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable behind view click event Framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377593/how-to-disable-behind-view-click-event-framelayout)

Answer (score 114):

Just setting the `android:clickable="true"` property for the LinearLayout in the XML will prevent the clicks going through -- no need for a click listener.

Comment: the only problem with that is that pressed state propagates to all child controls of the view that has clickable set to true. e.g. buttons do click animations when you click on the background.

Comment: Also add     android:focusable="true" to remove lint warning

Answer (score 2):

Assigned a click to Linear Layout and that solved it. Honestly it should not be working like this to begin with but that solved the problem. The click is empty.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to put the LinearLayout before the inner RelativeLayout in the xml.