# How to disable behind view click event Framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-framelayout, android-gui

Here i have one view pager activity which has one imageview and 2 overlay bars. there overlay bars i made using android xml file layout itself.

Here my requirement is like that

1) single tap on view pager's imageview first time  = show top and bottom rectangle overlaybar.
2) single tap on view pager's imageview second time = hide these overlays.

These both are functions like android gallary view type.

But here when these top and bottom layout bar displays at that time i want to use only buttons click only which buttons are declare within this layout.

But I am not getting success to achieve this thing.

Problems

1) when `top or bottom bar` is there if i can click on `next or previous` button than its takes event for behind imageview single tap touch event, And my bar is getting invisible.
2) Only wants declare buttons event only
3) Avoid imageview getting clicked when i touch to overlay bar.

In short when my top and bottom image bar appears at that time no touh event takes place for imageview from top and bottom image bar. I can click on imageview but not making clickable when i click on actually next or previous or share button.

So these are the problems which i am facing, Please help me .

Source code :

**activity_pager_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_top_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/slideshow_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_top_overlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/slideshow_bar"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_left_arrow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_below_share"
            style="@style/normalText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_left_arrow"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_right_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

item_pager_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <demo.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</FrameLayout>
```

JAVA code

```
public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String STATE_POSITION = "STATE_POSITION";
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private String[] imageUrls;
    private ViewPager pager;

    private static int sCounter = 0;

    private RelativeLayout mRlTopOverlayBar = null;
    private RelativeLayout mRlBottomOverlayBar = null;
    private TextView mPageNumberText = null;
    private Button mLeftArrow = null;
    private Button mRightArrow = null;

    int mPageCounter = 0;
    int mTotalImages = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_pager);

        mRlTopOverlayBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_top_overlay);
        mRlBottomOverlayBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottom_overlay);

        mPageNumberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_top_overlay);
        mLeftArrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_left_arrow);
        mRightArrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_right_arrow);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] imageUrls = bundle
                .getStringArray(Constants.GALLARY_IMAGES_IMAGE_BUNDLE_KEY);

        mTotalImages = imageUrls.length;

        mPageCounter = bundle.getInt(
                Constants.GALLARY_IMAGE_POSITION_BUNDLE_KEY, 0);

        Log.d("TAG", "Pre Poistion " + mPageCounter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mPageCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
        }

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.photo_default)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).resetViewBeforeLoading()
                .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
        pager.setCurrentItem(mPageCounter);

        mLeftArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // int setCounter = mPageCounter - 1;
                // if (setCounter >= 0) {

                // }
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);

            }
        });

        mRightArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                /*
                 * int setCounter = mPageCounter + 1; if (setCounter <
                 * mTotalImages) { pager.setCurrentItem(mPageCounter + 1); }
                 */
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private String[] images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
            this.images = images;
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View container) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image,
                    view, false);

            Log.d("TAG", "Poistion " + position);
            final ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) imageLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);

            final DeactivableViewPager viewPager = new DeactivableViewPager(
                    ImagePagerActivity.this);
            imageView.setOnScaleListener(new OnPageScaleListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScaleBegin() {
                    viewPager.deactivate();
                }

                @Override
                public void onScaleEnd(float scale) {
                    if (scale > 1.0) {
                        viewPager.deactivate();
                    } else {
                        viewPager.activate();
                    }
                }
            });

            imageView
                    .setSingleTapListener(new OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {
                            Log.d("TAG", "setSingleTapListener");

                            sCounter++;
                            if (sCounter % 2 == 0) {
                                mRlTopOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mRlBottomOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                mRlTopOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mRlBottomOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mRlBottomOverlayBar.setClickable(false);
                                mRlTopOverlayBar.setClickable(false);
                            }
                        }
                    });

            imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options,
                    new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            // spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                FailReason failReason) {
                            String message = null;
                            switch (failReason.getType()) {
                            case IO_ERROR:
                                message = "Input/Output error";
                                break;
                            case DECODING_ERROR:
                                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                                break;
                            case NETWORK_DENIED:
                                message = "Downloads are denied";
                                break;
                            case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                                break;
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                message = "Unknown error";
                                break;
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

            ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View container) {
        }

    }
}
```

**image :**

[image]

thanks

Comment: I know this is 5 years too late, but what I discovered is your homescreen should be a fragment. Don't add controls to 'activity_main' or 'content_main' other than a framelayout to hold fragments. Adding controls to the main activity's layout will cause overlaying fragments to fire events for the main activity's controls when the same coordinates are pressed. Set each fragment's parent layout to 'android:clickable="true"'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 imageView.setSingleTapListener(new OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {
                        Log.d("TAG", "setSingleTapListener");

                        sCounter++;
                        if (sCounter % 2 == 0) {
                            mRlTopOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mRlBottomOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pager.requestFocus();
                        } else {
                            mRlTopOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mRlBottomOverlayBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mRlTopOverlayBar.requestFocus();
                            mRlBottomOverlayBar.requestFocus();
                            mRlBottomOverlayBar.setClickable(true);
                            mRlTopOverlayBar.setClickable(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 321):

A better way is to set the top and bottom frame to be clickable, with:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Doing so will make sure that the view/frame itself will trap all clicking events, and will not pass it through the view behind it. Note this method works for all layout/view/controls, but many controls (such as buttons) already have this function on by default.

Comment: This works only if the lower view is not a button. Otherwise the button is still picking up the click event.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer is a hack

Comment: Well, doesn't work for me, the listview behind it still gets tapped

Comment: To test this if you turn on Accessiblity/Talkback then you would see the items selected on the back of the screen

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: in this case.. I agree click is trapped... but a ripple effect is shown when we add clickalbe true to a linear or relative layout

Comment: @Kaspis245 Sure, use `view.setClickable(true)`, see here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setClickable(boolean)

Comment: Yes, this solution works fine, but be aware that if you need to implement Talkback mode it will announce the view as clickable. So it might be confusing for some users, who rely on Talkback.

Answer (score 21):

`android:clickable="true"` for top and bottom bar.

or give each `FrameLayout` an `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 19):

just add this to each of your framelayout view containers so that absorb the click:

```
  android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 17):

By default, some controls have `clickable` property as `true`.
But the layout doesn't. For layout, we have to make them explicitly clickable so that it will grab the events of clicks or touches and will not let it pass to background views. This is how we do it:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Add these lines to all your layouts, so that it will grab/absorb events and will not let it pass to background views.

Answer (score 5):

@gordon1hd1 answer is correct but for those who are still confused, I am adding my layout which contains a `FrameLayout` as parent and a `LinearLayout` and two`ImageViews` as childs.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">         
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrowLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_back"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="#3f808080"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrowRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_back"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="#3f808080"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Previously, the `Linearlayout` was also intercepting touch events when either of `ImageViews` were pressed. Adding `android:clickable="true"` to both `ImageViews` resolved the issue.

If you are also facing this type of issue, add `android:clickable="true"` to the view you want to trap the clicking event.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, Set android:clickable="true" in xml to your foreground view.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to `rl_bottom_overlay` and `rl_top_overlay`. If you don´t set click events to these layouts (nor via XML neither programatically), no events will be triggered on background views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/llSettings"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ff106279"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSettings1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#ff000f"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="buttonclick"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
public void click(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "((RelativeLayout)v).toString()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void buttonclick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// For removing click event, sometime click=true not work

```
relBottomConfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    return;
                }
            });
```