# click on empty space in fragment executes activity event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an `Activity` which consists of 4 images and `onClick` of any image I'm opening a `Fragment`. Also, I have a `Navigation Drawer` where the profile option opens up a `fragment`. Since the fields in my `ProfileFragment` are few there is allot of empty space. And if the user clicks on the empty space, the click event of the image placed in the `Activity` is executed and that particular `Fragment` opens up. I have tried to set the background color of the `profilefragment` to `white`, but it did not work.

**ProfileFragment class :**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    return view;
}
```

**profile_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.six30labs.mis.fragments.ProfileFragment">  

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

               <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/empCompanyName"
                        style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"                            
                        android:hint="Company Name"
                        android:inputType="text" />


               <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/empPhoneNumber"
                        style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
                        android:hint="Employee PhNo"
                        android:inputType="text" />

               <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/empEmail"
                        style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
                        android:hint="Employee Email"
                        android:inputType="text" />

             <Button
                     android:id="@+id/editProfileBtn"
                     android:text="Edit"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      />
   </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

On click of the Profile Option in the `Navigation Drawer` I'm using the following line to open up the fragment :

```
   fragment = new ProfileFragment();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view,fragment).addToBackStack("Profile").commit();
```

How do I fix this issue? Kindly help me out please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable behind view click event Framelayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377593/how-to-disable-behind-view-click-event-framelayout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write this code in root layout of your fragment

```
android:clickable="true"
```

in your case it is `FrameLayout` so

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="com.six30labs.mis.fragments.ProfileFragment">
```

Comment: Hey thanks allot! that solved the issue ! Will surely read about that  :)